# Date-bound running average in Postgresql - how to partition into four weeks

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a table with sales_date (weekly: every Saturday), item_ID, and sales. I want a four-week running average. I need to partition my data into four-week sections per ID, but I can't work out how to do the syntax.

Sample table:

```
ID  date    value   four_wk_average
<p>123  04/05/2019  1640.88 1640.88
<p>123  11/05/2019  2093.4  1867.14
<p>123  18/05/2019  2671.57 2135.28
<p>123  25/05/2019  2034.6  2110.11
<p>123  01/06/2019  1564.62 2001.01
<p>123  08/06/2019  2143.29 2024.73
<p>123  15/06/2019  2007    2022.19
<p>123  22/06/2019  2329.35 2060.59
<p>123  29/06/2019  2794.32 2142.11
<p>123  06/07/2019  3380.05 2265.91
```

When I run the below code I get the rightmost column - it's a running average but it takes ALL the rows rather than just the current row and previous three that I want.

```
select
id,
date,
value,
avg(value) over (partition by id, (x.date between x.date and x.date - '22 days'::interval) order by date)

from
(select id, date::date, value from sales where date >= '2019-05-01') x
```

The correct values would be

```
ID  date    value   four_wk_average
<p>123  04/05/2019  1640.88 1640.88
<p>123  11/05/2019  2093.4  1867.14
<p>123  18/05/2019  2671.57 2135.28
<p>123  25/05/2019  2034.6  2110.11
<p>123  01/06/2019  1564.62 2091.05
<p>123  08/06/2019  2143.29 2103.52
<p>123  15/06/2019  2007    1937.38
<p>123  22/06/2019  2329.35 2011.07
<p>123  29/06/2019  2794.32 2318.49
<p>123  06/07/2019  3380.05 2627.68
```

I think my partition is taking my interval part as a boolean test and just returning TRUE - I don't know how to represent a date range in the windowed function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=42f176134c9a4359698df62bb29d494d)

Way 1: This works for **Postgres 11+** and several records per week

```
SELECT
    *,
    AVG(value) OVER (ORDER BY the_date RANGE BETWEEN interval '4 weeks - 1 day' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM
    sales
```

The interval is 4 weeks long: 4 weeks minus 1 day plus the current day.

---

Way 2: This works also for **Postgres <11** and only if there is really **only one record per week**:

```
SELECT
    *,
    AVG(value) OVER (ORDER BY the_date ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM
    sales
```

---

[Further reading](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/07/05/postgresql-11s-support-for-sql-standard-groups-and-exclude-window-function-clauses/) on window functions and `ROWS` and `RANGE` clauses

---

Way 3: This is the way for **Postgres version <11** and **several records per week**:

```
SELECT 
    s1.*,
    (SELECT AVG(s2.value)
     FROM sales s2
     WHERE s2.the_date <= s1.the_date
          AND s2.the_date > s1.the_date - interval '4 weeks')
FROM sales s1;
```

Comment: Lifesaver: I used Way 2 and it worked perfectly. Thanks also for the further reading - I had tried to search the internet for how to do this and I couldn't find anything. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi! I'm so sorry for not answering it sooner. This does not work when I have all my data together - in this situation, the data is grouped by country as well as ID. Which of your three options are best for this situation? Thinking in an Excel way, I would like to do an AVERAGEIFS with the conditions being that the ID and country match. Or is there any ordering I can do to my subquery that I am doing this on that will make the PRECEDING ROW syntax work? Thank you!

Comment: Nevertheless, of course I could try to help you. But in that case I really need sample data and expected output as well. So please try to create a fiddle (as I did in my answer) and/or open a completely new question!